# Showing a Windows application in an Ubuntu window

Tags: windows, window, window-manager, x11-forwarding

My host machine is Ubuntu. It is always painful to run a virtual host to use MS office or the other windows applications. I don't mind about the cost of machines but the convenience is my top variety. Is it possible to show a Windows' application hosted in windows in a Linux environment? Either by using a virtual machine or even using two PC's at the same time as shown in the image?

I do not like to show the entire VM window and another window within it.

How is this configuration possible?

[image: Ubuntu windows application]

Comment: I think Virtualbox seemless mode is what you are looking for, but I have never used this myself.

Comment: Either use wine, if the app runs in it, or run it full screen on vbox, but vbox in window mode. No other options.

Comment: @Bruni, Many thanks. I tested  it. This idea does not work at the moment for me.  [link](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14493)

Comment: @JacobVlijm, MS Office does not work under Wine. Tried all possible ways. Full screen covers Ubuntu application windows which is not a convenient option.